How to throttle network for a single docker container
For a crowdsourcing application I need a server that can do the following:

Host a WebRTC call between 2 clients
Simulate various network conditions (low bandwith, delay, etc.) and switch between them
Handle multiple of these video calls with manipulated network at the same time, each with different network manipulations

I have succesfully used the the official Coturn Docker container to spin up a single TURN server and make a video call over it.
How can I now introduce network artifacts into this setup? Ultimately I will probably need an own TURN server for every single ongoing call, so that I can manipulate the network strength individually.
Steps Taken

I tried using tc inside the container, but the Coturn Docker Image doesn't have that (or any other shell utility) installed.
This answer seems like a way to do it from outside the container, but I get the same errors as described in the comments and no solution is provided.

